# How to package iOS app for enterprise deployment with all icons?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

Not too sure if this is programming-related enough.

I'm using Xcode 9.2.

My organization is looking to deploy a custom iOS app built using our Apple Enterprise account. We are using Blackberry UEM to deploy the app. The problem we're seeing right now is that the high-res app store icon in Assets.xcassets gets stripped out when archiving my IPA, so when we add it to UEM, the icon looks quite bad in the UEM store page. I've tried playing around with the archive settings, including app thinning, compiling from bitcode and stripping swift symbols.

How can I force Xcode to leave the store icon in my xcassets in the final built ipa file?

Comment: This is only a guess, but I think this is happening because you're making an enterprise provisioned app. This icon is only used in the App Store, so Xcode strips it out since it's not an App Store build. I wouldn't imagine there's any straightforward way of getting around this when you're packaging for enterprise deployment.

Comment: That's what I'm worried about. If anyone has solved this issue, I'd love to hear about it.